# List Comprehension Loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with date, time., price, mag, signal. 
62035 rows; there are 42 times of day associated to each unique date in the file.

For each date, when there is an 'S' in the signal column append the corresponding price at the time the 'S' occurred. Below is the attempt.

```
from pandas import *
from numpy import *
from io import *
from os import *
from sys import *

DF1 = read_csv('___.csv')
idf=DF1.set_index(['date','time','price'],inplace=True)
sStore=[]
for i in idf.index[i][0]:
  sStore.append([idf.index[j][2] for j in idf[j][1] if idf['signal']=='S'])
sStore.head()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-8769220929e4> in <module>()
  1 sStore=[]
  2 
----> 3 for time in idf.index[i][0]:
  4 
  5     sStore.append([idf.index[j][2] for j in idf[j][1] if idf['signal']=='S'])

 NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

I do not understand why the i index is not permitted here. Thanks.

I also think it's strange that :

idf.index.levels[0] will show the dates "not parsed" as it is in the file but out of order. Despite that  parse_date=True as an argument in set_index.

I bring this up since I was thinking of side swiping the problem with something like:

```
for i in idf.index.levels[0]:

   sStore.append([idf.index[j][2] for j in idf.index.levels[1] if idf['signal']=='S'])

 sStore.head()
```

**My edit 12/30/2012 based on DSM's comment below:**

I would like to use your idea to get the P&L, as I commented below. Where if S!=B, for any given date, we difference using the closing time, 1620.

```
v=[df["signal"]=="S"]
t=[df["time"]=="1620"]
u=[df["signal"]!="S"]

df["price"][[v and (u and t)]]
```

That is, "give me the price at 1620; (even when it doesn't give a "sell signal", S) so that I can diff. with the "extra B's"--for the special case where B>S. This ignores the symmetric concern (where S>B) but for now I want to understand this logical issue.

On traceback, this expression gives:

```
ValueError: boolean index array should have 1 dimension
```

Note that in order to invoke df["time'] **I do not set_index here**. Trying the union operator | gives:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'list' and 'list'
```

**Looking at Max Fellows's approach**,

@Max Fellows

The point is to close out the positions at the end of the day; so we need to capture to price at the close to "unload" all those B, S which were accumulated; but didn't net each other out.
If I say:

```
filterFunc1 = lambda row: row["signal"] == "S" and ([row["signal"] != "S"][row["price"]=="1620"])
filterFunc2 =lambda row: ([row["price"]=="1620"][row["signal"] != "S"])

filterFunc=filterFunc1 and filterFunc2

filteredData = itertools.ifilter(filterFunc, reader)
```

On traceback:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: The variable `i` is being created during your iteration (`for i`), but you are using `i` in determining the object over which to iterate (`idf.index[i][0]`). Since the `idf.index[i][0]` part will be evaluated first, and since there is no value for `i` at that point, the error will be thrown.

Comment: @phihag If I want to "do algorithm" restricted to those 42 times of day, for all days. How might I fix this? Do you see other problems with the list comprehension above? Thank you.

Comment: Unrelated, but you **really** don't want to do all those `*`-imports.  `from numpy import *` will replace the builtin `any` with `numpy`'s any, which doesn't handle genexps, and so `any((False for i in range(3))) == True`; `from os import *` will replace `open` with `os.open`, and so most `open` calls will return `TypeError: an integer is required`; and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using @Max Fellows' handy example data, we can have a look at it in `pandas`.  [BTW, you should always try to provide a short, self-contained, correct example (see [here](http://sscce.org/) for more details), so that the people trying to help you don't have to spend time coming up with one.]

First, `import pandas as pd`.  Then:

```
In [23]: df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv", names="date time price mag signal".split())

In [24]: df.set_index(["date", "time"], inplace=True)
```

which gives me

```
In [25]: df
Out[25]: 
                 price      mag signal
date       time                       
12/28/2012 1:30     10      foo      S
           2:15     11      bar      N
           3:00     12      baz      S
           4:45     13   fibble      N
           5:30     14  whatsit      S
           6:15     15     bobs      N
           7:00     16  widgets      S
           7:45     17  weevils      N
           8:30     18   badger      S
           9:15     19    moose      S
11/29/2012 1:30     10      foo      N
           2:15     11      bar      N
           3:00     12      baz      S
           4:45     13   fibble      N
           5:30     14  whatsit      N
           6:15     15     bobs      N
           7:00     16  widgets      S
           7:45     17  weevils      N
           8:30     18   badger      N
           9:15     19    moose      N
[etc.]
```

We can see which rows have a signal of `S` easily:

```
In [26]: df["signal"] == "S"
Out[26]: 
date        time
12/28/2012  1:30     True
            2:15    False
            3:00     True
            4:45    False
            5:30     True
            6:15    False
[etc..]
```

and we can select using this too:

```
In [27]: df["price"][df["signal"] == "S"]
Out[27]: 
date        time
12/28/2012  1:30    10
            3:00    12
            5:30    14
            7:00    16
            8:30    18
            9:15    19
11/29/2012  3:00    12
            7:00    16
12/29/2012  3:00    12
            7:00    16
8/9/2008    3:00    12
            7:00    16
Name: price
```

This is a `DataFrame` with every date, time, and price where there's an `S`.  And if you simply want a list:

```
In [28]: list(df["price"][df["signal"] == "S"])
Out[28]: [10.0, 12.0, 14.0, 16.0, 18.0, 19.0, 12.0, 16.0, 12.0, 16.0, 12.0, 16.0]
```

**Update**:

`v=[df["signal"]=="S"]` makes `v` a Python `list` containing a `Series`.  That's not what you want.  `df["price"][[v and (u and t)]]` doesn't make much sense to me either --: `v` and `u` are mutually exclusive, so if you and them together, you'll get nothing.  For these logical vector ops you can use `&` and `|` instead of `and` and `or`.  Using the reference data again:

```
In [85]: import pandas as pd

In [86]: df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv", names="date time price mag signal".split())

In [87]: v=df["signal"]=="S"

In [88]: t=df["time"]=="4:45"

In [89]: u=df["signal"]!="S"

In [90]: df[t]
Out[90]: 
          date  time  price     mag signal
3   12/28/2012  4:45     13  fibble      N
13  11/29/2012  4:45     13  fibble      N
23  12/29/2012  4:45     13  fibble      N
33    8/9/2008  4:45     13  fibble      N

In [91]: df["price"][t]
Out[91]: 
3     13
13    13
23    13
33    13
Name: price

In [92]: df["price"][v | (u & t)]
Out[92]: 
0     10
2     12
3     13
4     14
6     16
8     18
9     19
12    12
13    13
16    16
22    12
23    13
26    16
32    12
33    13
36    16
Name: price
```

[Note: this question has now become too long and meandering.  I suggest spending some time working through the examples in the `pandas` documentation at the console to get a feel for it.]

Comment: @MaxFellows & DSM: Thank you to you both!  I'd like to implement it both ways for practice. Would you mind looking at the above edit?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
for i in range(len(idf.index)):
  value = idf.index[i][0]
```

Same thing for the iteration with the `j` index variable. As has been pointed, you can't reference the iteration index in the expression to be iterated, and besides you need to perform a very specific iteration (traversing over a column in a matrix), and Python's default iterators won't work "out of the box" for this, so a custom index handling is needed here.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I think you're trying to accomplish based on your edit: for every date in your CSV file, group the date along with a list of prices for each item with a signal of "S".

You didn't include any sample data in your question, so I made a test one that I hope matches the format you described:

```
12/28/2012,1:30,10.00,"foo","S"
12/28/2012,2:15,11.00,"bar","N"
12/28/2012,3:00,12.00,"baz","S"
12/28/2012,4:45,13.00,"fibble","N"
12/28/2012,5:30,14.00,"whatsit","S"
12/28/2012,6:15,15.00,"bobs","N"
12/28/2012,7:00,16.00,"widgets","S"
12/28/2012,7:45,17.00,"weevils","N"
12/28/2012,8:30,18.00,"badger","S"
12/28/2012,9:15,19.00,"moose","S"
11/29/2012,1:30,10.00,"foo","N"
11/29/2012,2:15,11.00,"bar","N"
11/29/2012,3:00,12.00,"baz","S"
11/29/2012,4:45,13.00,"fibble","N"
11/29/2012,5:30,14.00,"whatsit","N"
11/29/2012,6:15,15.00,"bobs","N"
11/29/2012,7:00,16.00,"widgets","S"
11/29/2012,7:45,17.00,"weevils","N"
11/29/2012,8:30,18.00,"badger","N"
11/29/2012,9:15,19.00,"moose","N"
12/29/2012,1:30,10.00,"foo","N"
12/29/2012,2:15,11.00,"bar","N"
12/29/2012,3:00,12.00,"baz","S"
12/29/2012,4:45,13.00,"fibble","N"
12/29/2012,5:30,14.00,"whatsit","N"
12/29/2012,6:15,15.00,"bobs","N"
12/29/2012,7:00,16.00,"widgets","S"
12/29/2012,7:45,17.00,"weevils","N"
12/29/2012,8:30,18.00,"badger","N"
12/29/2012,9:15,19.00,"moose","N"
8/9/2008,1:30,10.00,"foo","N"
8/9/2008,2:15,11.00,"bar","N"
8/9/2008,3:00,12.00,"baz","S"
8/9/2008,4:45,13.00,"fibble","N"
8/9/2008,5:30,14.00,"whatsit","N"
8/9/2008,6:15,15.00,"bobs","N"
8/9/2008,7:00,16.00,"widgets","S"
8/9/2008,7:45,17.00,"weevils","N"
8/9/2008,8:30,18.00,"badger","N"
8/9/2008,9:15,19.00,"moose","N"
```

And here's a method using Python 2.7 and built-in libraries to group it in the way it sounds like you want:

```
import csv
import itertools
import time
from collections import OrderedDict

with open("sample.csv", "r") as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file,
                            fieldnames=["date", "time", "price", "mag", "signal"])

    # Reduce the size of the data set by filtering out the non-"S" rows.
    filterFunc = lambda row: row["signal"] == "S"
    filteredData = itertools.ifilter(filterFunc, reader)

    # Sort by date so we can use the groupby function.
    dateKeyFunc = lambda row: time.strptime(row["date"], r"%m/%d/%Y")
    sortedData = sorted(filteredData, key=dateKeyFunc)

    # Group by date: create a new dictionary of date to a list of prices.
    datePrices = OrderedDict((date, [row["price"] for row in rows])
                             for date, rows
                             in itertools.groupby(sortedData, dateKeyFunc))

for date, prices in datePrices.iteritems():
    print "{0}: {1}".format(time.strftime(r"%m/%d/%Y", date),
                            ", ".join(str(price) for price in prices))

>>> 08/09/2008: 12.00, 16.00
>>> 11/29/2012: 12.00, 16.00
>>> 12/28/2012: 10.00, 12.00, 14.00, 16.00, 18.00, 19.00
>>> 12/29/2012: 12.00, 16.00
```

The type conversions are up to you, since you may be using other libraries to do your CSV reading, but that should hopefully get you started -- and take careful note of @DSM's comment about import *.

Comment: I ran your example; it provides all the 'S' prices with the dates in a peculiar order: 3/4/2009, 3/4/2008,1/14/2009,1/14/2008, 5/1/2012,3/5/2008,3/5/2009,...,etc.
Would you comment on why the order of the dates is like so? I ask because, it will be important for what I really need to do: Write a P&L function which computes, for each day, the sum(S_i-B_i) for all i, in a given date. And return the P&L number for all dates in the file. (In the case that num ('B') != num ('S'), for some day, I would like to consider subtracting to/from the close price (here 1620).

Comment: Where do you define 'rows', where you call 'rows' to construct datePrices?  Thanks very much.

Comment: Edited my response to include date conversion -- the odd order was because I had originally left out type conversions, so it was being sorted in string order (and then the dict at the end destroyed the order) - although after the extra detail in your comment, there are better ways of accomplishing your end goal; you might consider loading your CSV file into a database and querying it. See http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html for docs on the time conversion functions.

Comment: 'rows' is the second element of the tuple returned by the call to itertools.groupby -- the first element is the key defined by dateKeyFunc: effectively it's yielding the date and an iterator for all of the "S" rows falling under that date.

Comment: One way you might change the above code to meet your needs is to remove the initial filter part, which will leave you with all your rows grouped by date, and then you can use Python's built-in 'sum' function along with an ifilter to get the sums of different signal values at the end ("S"/"B"). If you get stuck, please let me know and I'll update my answer again.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `i` is not yet defined, just like the error message says.

In this line:

```
for i in idf.index[i][0]:
```

You are telling the Python interpreter to iterate over all the values yielded by the list returning from the expression `idf.index[i][0]` but you have not yet defined what `i` is (although you are attempting to set each item in the list to the variable `i` as well).

The way the Python `for ... in ...` loop works is that it takes the right most component and asks for the `next` item from the iterator.  It then assigns the value yielded by the call to the variable name provided on the left hand side.